# How to properly use std::forward in variadic/template class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I'm having some problem with my std::forward constructor for my template "matrix" class. Basically i want to set a matrix of type float and size 4 equal to the sum of 2 matrices of type float and size 3. I do this inside of my struct 'matrix_struct' in the function 'test'. However, MSVC error tells me that "'static_cast': cannot convert from 'matrix' to 'float'" and whenever I inspect the error it takes me to the 3rd matrix constructor with std::forward.

```
///////////////////////////////////
somefile.hpp

#pragma once

#include "matrix.hpp"

using matrix3 = matrix<float, 3>;
using matrix4 = matrix<float, 4>;

struct matrix_struct {
  matrix4 sum;

  void test(const matrix3& a, const matrix3& b) 
  {
     sum = a + b;
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////
matrix.hpp

#pragma once

#include <array>

template <typename t, size_t dim>
class matrix
{
public:
   matrix() { data.fill(static_cast<t>(0) }

   explicit matrix(const std::array<t, dim>& a) : data(a) {}

   template <typename... args_t>
   matrix(args_t... args) : data{ static_cast<t>(std::forward<args_t>(args))... } }

public:
   t& at(const size_t index)
   {
      return data.at(index >= dim ? dim - 1 : index);
   }

   const t& at(const size_t index) const
   {
      return data.at(index >= dim ? dim - 1 : index);
   }

public:
   matrix& operator = (const matrix<t, dim>& other)
   {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
         at(i) = other.at(i);
      }
      return *this;
   }

   matrix& operator = (const std::array<t, dim>& other)
   {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
         at(i) = other.at(i);
      }
      return *this;
   }

   matrix& operator = (const t& other) 
   {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
          at(i) = other;
      }
      return *this;
   }

public:
   matrix operator + (const matrix<t, dim>& other) const
   {
      matrix<t, dim> ret;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
         ret.at(i) = at(i) + other.at(i);
      }
      return ret;
   }

   matrix operator + (const std::array<t, dim>& other) const
   {
      matrix<t, dim> ret;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
         ret.at(i) = at(i) + other.at(i);
      }
      return ret;
   }

   matrix operator + (const t& other) const
   {
      matrix<t, dim> ret;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
         ret.at(i) = at(i) + other;
      }
      return ret;
   }

private:
   std::array<t, dim> data;
};
```

Comment: Um, it looks like it would be better to rename your `matrix` to `vector`, since its apparently always a 1D matrix of N elements.... **Anyways,**: Because the types of `a` and `b` are different in the expression `a + b`, and because of the signature of your overloaded `+` operator, an *implicit conversion* will be attempted to harmonize the types (performance killer); The suitable *converting constructor* you have is your variadic constructor, which just doesn't do it's job... I mean, you cannot "simply" cast `std::array<float, 4>` to `std::array<float, 3`.

Comment: you have capital T and lower case t all over the place

Comment: @WhiZTiM Would another constructor like this be needed then? `template <size_t dim_2>
 matrix(const matrix<t, dim_2>& other)
 {
  for (auto i = 0; i < (std::min)(dim, dim_2); ++i) {
   at(i) = other.at(i);
  }
 }` PS: As far as the naming goes, it will have multiple dimensions, i'm just testing for now and saw this error.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Also, I just noticed. You said a and b are different types which is not correct. a and b are both of type matrix3. sum is of type matrix4.

Comment: `args_t... args`...`forward<args_t>(args)` doesn't sound right in any case. You probably mean `args_t&&... args`...`forward<args_t>(args)`. Start from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem of your code sample is addressed by @RichardHodges's answer.
Assuming you include his solution to overcome tricky copy/move constructor selection, another problem remains: you do not offer a matrix promotion/demotion service through your constructors/assignment operators.

Therefore, the following line in your test function:

```
sum = a + b; // a + b is a matrix<float, 3>, sum a matrix<float, 4>
```

Will trigger a call to the variadic template constructor and fail.

Starting from Richard's solution, you need to tweak a bit the SFINAE condition to extend it to matrices of any size. To do so, we will need a little `is_matrix` trait:

```
template <typename T, size_t Dim>
class matrix;    

template <typename T>
struct is_matrix : std::false_type {};

template <typename Num, size_t Size>
struct is_matrix<matrix<Num, Size> > : std::true_type {
    using value_type = Num;
};
```

Now the variadic template constructor becomes:

```
template <typename t, size_t dim>
class matrix
{
/* ... */
public:
/* ... */
    template
    <
        class Arg,
        class...Rest,
        std::enable_if_t
        <
            ! std::is_matrix
            <
                std::decay_t<Arg>
            >::value
        >* = nullptr
    >
    matrix(Arg&& arg, Rest&&...rest)
    {
        // code to construct from something that's not a matrix
        // this will no longer hijack copy constructors etc.
    }
};
```

Then, we need to add the proper `matrix` constructor along with the proper friend declaration:

```
template <typename t, typename dim>
class matrix {
public:
    template <typename OtherT, size_t OtherDim>
    friend class matrix;

    template <size_t OtherDim>
    matrix(matrix<t, OtherDim> const& other) {
        size_t i = 0;
        for (; i < min(OtherDim, dim); ++i) {
            data[i] = other.data[i];
        }
        for(; i < dim; ++i) {
            data[i] = t();
        }
    }

    template <typename OtherT,
              size_t OtherDim>
    matrix(matrix<OtherT, OtherDim> const&) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<t, OtherT>::value,
                      "value_type mismatch between matrices!");
    }        
    /* ... */
};
```

*Note: You need the friend declaration because `matrix<Type1, Dim1>` and `matrix<Type2, Dim2>` are completely different types whenever `Type1 != Type2` or `Dim1 != Dim2` and as such, you cannot access `matrix<OtherT, OtherDim>`'s private/protected members in `matrix<t, dim>` without that friend declaration.*

This implementation will initialize the target matrix by filling its data member with the content of the given matrix when the value types match:

- If the given matrix is bigger, it will be truncated.
- If the given matrix is smaller, the remaining elements will be 0 initialized

If the value types don't match, the less specialized `matrix<OtherT, OtherDim>` constructor is the only available overload and it triggers a compiler error through a `static_assert`.

You would also need to define the equivalent assigment operators... Which I left as exercises.

A demo of these constructors in action can be found on [<kbd>Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d9b7f9b3b064f0b)

Comment: Could you give an example of using the new variadic template constructor?

Comment: Also the 2nd ctor you provided works for initializing the matrix with a matrix of different type and size. I only want to be able to initialize it with a different size / be able to do addition etc, with operators of different sizes. The type should always stay constant. PS: could you elaborate why you are declaring the class of different T and Dim as friend? why is that needed?

Comment: @JohnWayne The variadic template constructor can be used just like before. I edited my answer to match your spec and explicited the reason behind the friend declaration

Comment: I don't think it can... the constructor fails whenever i call std::forward<Args>(args) to forward into data as i was doing before

Comment: @JohnWayne You're gonna have to be more specific about that!

Answer (score 2):

Template constructors are problematic. They often create code that is a better candidate than your other constructors.

The general solution is to disable the template if its decayed type matches the class you are writing.

example:

```
struct MyClass
{
    template
    <
        class Arg,
        class...Rest,
        std::enable_if_t
        <
            ! std::is_same
            <
                std::decay_t<Arg>,
                MyClass
            >::value
        >* = nullptr
    >
    MyClass(Arg&& arg, Rest&&...rest)
    {
        // code to construct from something that's not MyClass
        // this will no longer hijack copy constructors etc.
    }


};
```